# passing a single string value from sqlite database class to another class in android?

Tags: android, sqlite

I am making a hangman application for android my problem is that I need to pass a single word from my database class into my game class, I know that the game class works as I created it just using an array list originally, then I made a database class that I also know works as I can add words to it and view them.

The issue is that I can not seem to pass a single word from my database class through to my game class, I have spent 3 days on this now and tried many different things but with no luck, any help that could be given would be amazing as i feel I may need to throw my comp out the window soon.

this is my data base class

```
package com.example.hangpract;



import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Random;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;

public class mysteryWordDB {


    public static final String KEY_WORD="mystery_word";

    public static ArrayList<String> results = new ArrayList<String>();  
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME="HangManWords";
    private static final String DATABASE_TABLE="wordsTable";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION= 1;

    private DbHelper ourHelper;
    private final Context ourContext;
    private static SQLiteDatabase ourDatabase;

    private static class DbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{

        public DbHelper(Context context) {
            super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + DATABASE_TABLE + " (" +
                    KEY_WORD + " TEXT NOT NULL);"
                    );


        }

        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + DATABASE_TABLE);
            onCreate(db);

        }

    }

public mysteryWordDB(Context c){
    ourContext = c;
}

public mysteryWordDB open()throws SQLException{
    ourHelper = new DbHelper(ourContext);
    ourDatabase = ourHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    return this;
}

public void close(){
    ourHelper.close();
}
//method to add user words from the edit word class

public long createEntry(String word) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
    cv.put(KEY_WORD, word);
    return ourDatabase.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, cv);

}
//method to display all words in the view class

public String getData() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String[] columns = new String[]{KEY_WORD};
    Cursor c = ourDatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE, columns, null, null, null, null, null);
    String result = "";


    int iWord = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_WORD);

    for (c.moveToFirst(); !c.isAfterLast(); c.moveToNext()){
        result = result +  c.getString(iWord) + "\n";
    }
    return result;
}

//method that should set up an array of the words in the data base, can't get this bit right

public void getMysteryWord() {
    Cursor c = ourDatabase.rawQuery("SELECT KEY_WORD FROM " +
            DATABASE_TABLE, null);

    if (c != null ) {
        if  (c.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                String mystWord = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(KEY_WORD));

                results.add(mystWord.toString());
            }while (c.moveToNext());
        }}
    }



//method that is called from the game class to get a random string from the array to use in the game

    public static String  word(){
        Random rand = new Random();
    int i=rand.nextInt(results.size());
    if(i >-1)return results.get(i);

    return results.get(i);

}
}
```

the problem area being with the latest method I have tried is:

```
//method that should set up an array of the words in the data base, can't get this bit right

public void getMysteryWord() {
    Cursor c = ourDatabase.rawQuery("SELECT KEY_WORD FROM " +
            DATABASE_TABLE, null);

    if (c != null ) {
        if  (c.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                String mystWord = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(KEY_WORD));

                results.add(mystWord.toString());
            }while (c.moveToNext());
        }}
    }



//method that is called from the game class to get a random string from the array to use in the game

    public static String  word(){
        Random rand = new Random();
    int i=rand.nextInt(results.size());
    if(i >-1)return results.get(i);

    return results.get(i);

}
}
```

and then this is the game class where it needs to pass in a random instance of KEY_WORD:

```
package com.example.hangpract;




import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;



    public class game extends Activity implements OnClickListener {


        private ImageView hangimg;
        private TextView word;
        private String mysteryWord = mysteryWordDB.word();
        private int numWrongGuesses;


        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.game);

            bindviews();
            inistMystword();
            initWrongGuesses();



            //set button views for letters
            Button aButton = (Button)
                    this.findViewById(R.id.buttonA);

                    aButton.setOnClickListener(this);


            Button bButton = (Button)
                    this.findViewById(R.id.buttonB);

                    bButton.setOnClickListener(this);

            Button cButton = (Button)
                    this.findViewById(R.id.buttonC);

                    cButton.setOnClickListener(this);

            Button dButton = (Button)
                    this.findViewById(R.id.buttonD);

                    dButton.setOnClickListener(this);

            Button eButton = (Button)
                    this.findViewById(R.id.buttonE);

                    eButton.setOnClickListener(this);

            Button fButton = (Button)
                    this.findViewById(R.id.buttonF);

                    fButton.setOnClickListener(this);

            Button gButton = (Button)
                    this.findViewById(R.id.buttonG);

                    gButton.setOnClickListener(this);

            Button hButton = (Button)
                    this.findViewById(R.id.buttonH);

                    hButton.setOnClickListener(this);

            Button iButton = (Button)
                    this.findViewById(R.id.buttonI);

                    iButton.setOnClickListener(this);

            Button jButton = (Button)
                    this.findViewById(R.id.buttonJ);

                    jButton.setOnClickListener(this);

            Button kButton = (Button)
                    this.findViewById(R.id.buttonK);

                    kButton.setOnClickListener(this);

            Button lButton = (Button)
                    this.findViewById(R.id.buttonL);

                    lButton.setOnClickListener(this);

            Button mButton = (Button)
                    this.findViewById(R.id.buttonM);

                    mButton.setOnClickListener(this);

            Button nButton = (Button)
                    this.findViewById(R.id.buttonN);

                    nButton.setOnClickListener(this);

            Button oButton = (Button)
                    this.findViewById(R.id.buttonO);

                    oButton.setOnClickListener(this);

            Button pButton = (Button)
                    this.findViewById(R.id.buttonP);

                    pButton.setOnClickListener(this);

            Button qButton = (Button)
                    this.findViewById(R.id.buttonQ);

                    qButton.setOnClickListener(this);

            Button rButton = (Button)
                    this.findViewById(R.id.buttonR);

                    rButton.setOnClickListener(this);

            Button sButton = (Button)
                    this.findViewById(R.id.buttonS);

                    sButton.setOnClickListener(this);

            Button tButton = (Button)
                    this.findViewById(R.id.buttonT);

                    tButton.setOnClickListener(this);

            Button uButton = (Button)
                    this.findViewById(R.id.buttonU);

                    uButton.setOnClickListener(this);

            Button vButton = (Button)
                    this.findViewById(R.id.buttonV);

                    vButton.setOnClickListener(this);

            Button wButton = (Button)
                    this.findViewById(R.id.buttonW);

                    wButton.setOnClickListener(this);

            Button xButton = (Button)
                    this.findViewById(R.id.buttonX);

                    xButton.setOnClickListener(this);

            Button yButton = (Button)
                    this.findViewById(R.id.buttonY);

                    yButton.setOnClickListener(this);

            Button zButton = (Button)
                    this.findViewById(R.id.buttonZ);

                    zButton.setOnClickListener(this);




            //sets button view for new game
            Button newbutton = (Button)
                    this.findViewById(R.id.buttNew);
                    newbutton.setOnClickListener(this);
            //sets button view for menu
            Button menuButton = (Button)
                    this.findViewById(R.id.buttMenu);
                    menuButton.setOnClickListener(this);
        }


        //set actions on buttons
        public void onClick(View v) {
            switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.buttonA:

                validate('a');
                    break;
                case R.id.buttonB:

                validate('b');
                break;
                case R.id.buttonC:

                    validate('c');
                    break;
                case R.id.buttonD:

                    validate('d');
                    break;

                case R.id.buttonE:

                    validate('e');
                    break;

                case R.id.buttonF:

                    validate('f');
                    break;

                case R.id.buttonG:

                    validate('g');
                    break;

                case R.id.buttonH:

                    validate('h');
                    break;

                case R.id.buttonI:

                    validate('i');
                    break;

                case R.id.buttonJ:

                    validate('j');
                    break;

                case R.id.buttonK:

                    validate('k');
                    break;

                case R.id.buttonL:

                    validate('l');
                    break;

                case R.id.buttonM:

                    validate('m');
                    break;

                case R.id.buttonN:

                    validate('n');
                    break;

                case R.id.buttonO:

                    validate('o');
                    break;

                case R.id.buttonP:

                    validate('p');
                    break;

                case R.id.buttonQ:

                    validate('q');
                    break;

                case R.id.buttonR:

                    validate('r');
                    break;

                case R.id.buttonS:

                    validate('s');
                    break;

                case R.id.buttonT:

                    validate('t');
                    break;

                case R.id.buttonU:

                    validate('u');
                    break;

                case R.id.buttonV:

                    validate('v');
                    break;

                case R.id.buttonW:

                    validate('w');
                    break;

                case R.id.buttonX:

                    validate('x');
                    break;

                case R.id.buttonY:

                    validate('y');
                    break;

                case R.id.buttonZ:

                    validate('z');
                    break;




            case R.id.buttNew:


                Intent newGame = new Intent(v.getContext(), game.class);
                startActivityForResult(newGame,0);

            break;

            case R.id.buttMenu:
                Intent menu = new Intent(v.getContext(), MainActivity.class);
                startActivityForResult(menu,0);

            }


        }
        //get mystery word
        public void inistMystword(){
            word = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.mysteryword);
            word.setText(mysteryWord);

            word.setText(underscore());
        }


        //method to display the mystery word as underscores
        public String underscore() {
            StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer();
            for (int i = 0; i < mysteryWord.length(); i++) {
            result.append("_ ");
            }
            return result.toString();
            }


        //method to validate guess



        private void validate(char ch) {
            if (mysteryWord.indexOf(ch)== -1){


                if (numWrongGuesses < 6){
                    numWrongGuesses++;
                }
                checkLose();
                }
            else {
            if (numWrongGuesses <6){
                updateMystWord(ch);
                checkWin();
            } else {
                checkLose();
            }

        }}






            //method to reveal letter

            private void updateMystWord(char ch) {
                char[] updatedWord =
                word.getText().toString().toCharArray();
                for (int i = 0; i < mysteryWord.length(); i++) {

                if (ch == mysteryWord.charAt(i)) 
                updatedWord[i * 2] = mysteryWord.charAt(i);
                word.setText(new String(updatedWord));

                }



            }
            //sets number of wrong guesses to zero at game start
        private void initWrongGuesses() {
            numWrongGuesses = 0;
        }




        //checks when game is lost and displays lose screen

        private void checkLose() {
             if (numWrongGuesses == 6)
                hangimg.setImageResource(R.drawable.lose);


            }
        //checks when game is won and displays win screen
        private void checkWin() {
            if (word.getText().toString().indexOf("_") == -1) {
            hangimg.setImageResource(R.drawable.win);
            }
            }
        //binds the views
        private void bindviews(){
            hangimg = (ImageView)
                    this.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        }

      }
```

the game class definitely works and the database also works, I just can't figure out where I am going wrong with trying to pass a single value over for use in the game class any help at all would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Use public static String YOUR_VAR = "hi"; in database class, and in another class Use String var = ClassName.Your_Var;   please try this and let me know

Answer (score 1):

Make a method in your database file as.

```
static String str = "data";   // ASSUME TO PASS THIS STRING

public static String passData()
{
    return str;
}
```

Do this in your activity class.

```
  String str = dbClassName.passData();
```

Thats it.

Comment: using your example it worked in passing the word data to the game. but the issue i am really having is defining the string value as a single word from the database..

Comment: @Dave : I am not getting you properly,please explain in detail

Comment: I think what I am really looking for is the method to retrieve a random word from my database and to send that word to my game class as a string, the real issue is getting it from the database which needs to get just one random word this is what I am struggling on.